# Kubernetes pod fails while making call to google cloud pub/sub with unknown certificate autority

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a kubernetes cluster setup where I am trying to publish a message to google cloud pub/sub from my pod. When the POST call (created by the API behind the scenes) is being made by the pod, it fails citing the issue below:

`2016/07/21 10:31:24 Publish failed, Post https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-name>/topics/MyTopic:publish?alt=json: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I have already put a self signed certificate in the /etc/ssl/certs of my docker Debian image. Do I need to purchase a SSL certificate signed by some certified authority or will a self signed one do the job and I am missing something out here.

Comment: Does `pubsub.googleapis.com` resolve to the expected IP address? You shouldn't get any certificate warnings connecting to a google domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-signed certificates will not work. The certificate needs to be signed by a certificate authority.